# How does nginx know my servers url adress?

Tags: nginx

I installed nginx using `sudo apt-get install nginx`.

Now this allows me to go to `my_ip:port` and it allows me to visit the website. 
Yet, i can also do `my_url:port` and it will also direct me to the website.

How can nginx know my_url when I have not told it my_url anymore?

I was running Apache before, can that explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx was able to load via the fqdn `my_url:port` even though you haven't added `my_url` in the nginx config because config `default_server` (usually there by default) was specified.

`default_server` parameter specifies which block should serve a request if the server_name requested does not match any of the available server blocks:

For example

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nginx doesn't need it (at least, not yet). Your web browser looks up `my_url` in the DNS, and then uses `my_ip` (from DNS) `:port` (which you entered in your browser) to connect to Nginx.

Your Nginx is probably only configured with one site, which means any connection to it - regardless of whether it is by IP or by domain name - causes Nginx to serve that site. You can change this by going into your Nginx configuration files and setting (or changing) the value of the `server_name` parameter, for example:

`server { # You already have a server block somewhere in the config file
    listen       80; # Or 443, if you've enabled SSL
    server_name  example.com www.example.com; # Add (or change) this line to the list of addresses you want to answer to`